# Groovy script "unexpected token" with @ directive

Tags: groovy, compiler-errors

This has me totally baffled.

Specs: Linux Mint 18.3, Java 11, Groovy 2.5.9.

It may be of interest that these files are on an NTFS-formatted partition.

I make a simple Groovy script file with a simple @Grab:

```
package test;
@Grab(group='org.apache.commons', module='commons-lang3', version='3.7')
println "bye"
```

... fails:

```
org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
/media/chris/W10 D drive/My Documents/software projects/EclipseWorkspace/GroovyExp2020-03-08/src/test/testscript.groovy: 5: unexpected token: println @ line 5, column 1.
   println "bye"
   ^

1 error
```

If I comment out the `@Grab` line it runs OK.

If I make the script like this:

```
package test
def bosh = "jellow world"
bosh = "bash"
@Grab(group='org.apache.commons', module='commons-lang3', version='3.7')
bosh = "bish"
```

... the complaint, flagged for the last line there, changes to "Groovy:The current scope already contains a variable of the name bosh" (!).

If I put a semicolon at the end of the Grab line:

```
package test;
@Grab(group='org.apache.commons', module='commons-lang3', version='3.7');
println "bye"
```

... the complaint becomes "Unexpected token:;"

So far so bafflingly inexplicable. Even stranger is the fact, however, that some of my existing scripts still work OK: I can insert a `@Grab` line like the above, with no complaints about "unexpected token".

This is not Eclipse-generated nonsense: I get the same issues at the Linux CLI.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't just stick annotations anywhere in groovy (or Java)

You need to annotate a class, method or field

In your examples, you're annotating a variable assignment (which won't work), and a method call (which also won't work)

Move the annotation to the top of the file, or to a class definition

Comment: Thanks! Turns out to be a "schoolboy error" then.  But it seems to me to be odd to have to create a spurious class in order to rope in a general-purpose dependency.

Comment: You don't need to create a class. You can annotate package statement or import statements. Method call to println is not annotatable.